# Weekly class timetable IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, timetable

I have looked at existing calendar API's such as Kal but i was hoping for a good way to store lecture times for the week and display them in some sort of weekly view?

I wouldn't need to use the repeatInterval option with the datePicker because i only need lectures to be set for one week and remain the same

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This May help you
[tapku -calender](https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary)

[ios- calender](https://github.com/vgrichina/ios-calendar)

Comment: i have also had a look at tapku, its a good API but does it offer a weekly view instead of monthly?

Comment: this is day view https://github.com/muhku/calendar-ui?                and this is weekly view https://github.com/muhku/calendar-ui